# Appium java-client java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/appium/java_client/android/AndroidDriver;

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, junit, appium

**Run androidTest with appium java-client on Android Emulator Test failed as below errors:**
**I don't know how to fix, please help me, thanks!**

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/appium/java_client/android/AndroidDriver;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Native Method)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.getSortedDeclaredFields(TestClass.java:77)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.scanAnnotatedMembers(TestClass.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.(TestClass.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.createTestClass(ParentRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.(ParentRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.java:43)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(AndroidJUnit4Builder.java:65)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.AndroidRunnerBuilder.runnerForClass(AndroidRunnerBuilder.java:153)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.doCreateRunner(TestLoader.java:73)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.getRunnersFor(TestLoader.java:104)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:793)
    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:547)
    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:390)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2189)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication.test-Z4QneSzH9hljWZ6oCCYzMw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-LZo-ohg3r_r3B07VbxeQdA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.myapplication.test-Z4QneSzH9hljWZ6oCCYzMw==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.myapplication-LZo-ohg3r_r3B07VbxeQdA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    ... 19 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.example.myapplication-LZo-ohg3r_r3B07VbxeQdA==/base.apk because: Bad encoded_array value: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.example.myapplication-LZo-ohg3r_r3B07VbxeQdA==/base.apk': Bad encoded_value method type size 7
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:365)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:107)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:80)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:444)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:403)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.(DexPathList.java:164)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.(BaseDexClassLoader.java:126)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.(BaseDexClassLoader.java:101)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.(PathClassLoader.java:74)
    at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:87)
    at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:116)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:114)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries(ApplicationLoaders.java:60)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:851)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:950)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1188)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2462)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2454)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6343)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

**My app build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/spring.schemas'
        exclude 'META-INF/spring.handlers'
        exclude 'META-INF/versions/9'
        exclude 'META-INF/spring.tooling'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation group: 'io.appium', name: 'java-client', version: '7.3.0'
    implementation group: 'androidx.multidex', name: 'multidex', version: '2.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Supplementary conditions：Because of Duplicate class errors, I deleted duplicate class files in java-client

Comment: Supplementary conditions again：Because of Duplicate class errors, I change to deleted duplicate class files in selenium-api.jar, also had this issue